# Iterate through a list of items for multiple response.get API

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

How do I iterate through a list in order to add it to the request.get ?

```
import requests, json

url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="
# data = "Titanic"
data = "Titanic", "Avatar"
title_url = url + data


r = requests.get(title_url, '&apikey=xxx3432g')

print r.json
```

This works perfectly with only one title for *data* i do not know how to loop through it so I will get multiple titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first put all the titles you need into a list, and then pass those parameters as a dict, so

```
import requests

url = "http://www.omdbapi.com"
titles = ["Titanic", "Avatar"]
for title in titles:
    r = requests.get(url, params={"t":title, "apikey": "xxx3432g"})
    print(r.json())
```

EDIT:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.omdbapi.com"
titles = ["Titanic", "Avatar"]
output_results = []
for title in titles:
    r = requests.get(url, params={"t":title, "apikey": "xxx3432g"})
    output_results.append(r.json())

print(output_results[0]["Title"])
print(output_results[1]["Year"])
```

More details on http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Comment: Thanks for this, link was helpful too. It works but the r.json() stores only the last input *Avatar* (though when running the code it displays both). I was wanting to get particular results out of the response *like: title, year* for all entries. @Jim-Zhou

Comment: Well, you can simply make a list to which you can store the results.

`import requests

output_results = []

url = "http://www.omdbapi.com"

titles = ["Titanic", "Avatar"]

for title in titles:
    r = requests.get(url, params={"t":title, "apikey": xxx3432g"})
    output_results.append(r.json())

print(output_results)
`

Comment: But how to i get the elements from a list output_results[1]['Year']['Title'] doesn't work

Comment: output_results[1]["Year"] and output_results[1]["Title"] would be separate keys so you'd need to query them separately

Comment: This *output_results[0]["Year"],output_results[1]["Title"],output_results[0]["Year"],output_results[0]["Title"]* doesn't look good at all isn't it a way to convert this list to something else or a for loop or something to make this easier. I am planing on storing the results in either txt maybe csv format.

Comment: Just loop through the items on the list after you grab the items. So

`for output in output_results:`
    `with open("movies.csv", "a") as m:`
        `m.write("{},{},{},{}\n".format(output["Title"], output["Year"], output["Runtime"], output["Language"])`
Or however you want to access or output what you need

Comment: This seems to be the problem, I can't loop through it in anyway*Not that nested lists are my speciality* :) I get : *Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack*

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by loop through it? Can you show me the output_results and the final output you need?

Comment: >>> output_results
[{u'Plot': u'A seventeen-year-old aristocrat falls in love with a kind but poor artist aboard the luxurious, ill-fated R.M.S. Titanic.', u'Rated': u'PG-13', u'Title': u'Titanic', u'Ratings': [{u'Source': u'Internet Movie Database', u'Value': u'7.8/10'}, {u'Source': u'Rotten Tomatoes', u'Value': u'89%'}, {u'Source': u'Metacritic', u'Value': u'75/100'}], u'DVD': u'10 Sep 2012', u'Writer': u'James Cameron', u'Production': u'Paramount Pictures', u'Actors': u'Leonardo DiCaprio, Kate Winslet, Billy Zane, Kathy Bates', u'Type': u'movie', u'imdbVotes': u'934,048', u'Website':....

Comment: I need to get out something like *Title: Avatar, 2009, Directed by: James Cameron" and eventually put them in a txt or csv and include all the titles

Comment: I don't see a key for director in the output here, but if you just need 2-3 fields out of each output from the request, you should just directly get those particular values, possibly just in tuple or dict or whatever is more convenient. `output_results.append(r.json()["Title"], r.json()["Year"], r.json()["Director"])`

Then, since you already have all the fields you need, use format strings to make the output, whether by using format strings to make it into the output you specified above or put the values into a csv

Comment: There was a limit to pasting in the comments section. Anyway apparently the problem was that i was not capitalizing the first letter Year, Title, etc. It works now. Thanks you so so much!

Comment: I am having this problem when storing upload results to csv with the command you mentioned earlier. The problem is at one point in the list a Movie Title is not found in the API so it gets this response: *{'Response': 'False', 'Error': 'Movie not found!'}* after this point any other found title is not inserted into the csv.  I am assuming an if  statement is necessary

Comment: If the API doesn't find the movie title then the entire response should be different right? If you are reasonably sure that it's the only sort of error that could pop up in the json of tha request, something like `if "Error" not in output.keys()`

Comment: a try / except in the requests module seems impossible for me. Since this "Movie not found!" is the only error i am interested in right now wouldn't be easier to add something to the for loop *for output in output_results: with open("movies.csv", "a") as m: m.write("{},{},{},{}\n".format(output["Title"], output["Year"], output["Runtime"], output["Language"])" so it just skips it and pushes the next item?

Comment: I didn't suggest a try/except block, because returning a different json response doesn't raise an exception so you'd have to raise it yourself anyway. `if "Error" not in output.keys()` just checks whether a key is in the response and I assume a successful return won't have "Error" as a key.